# why do i not have to wrap in lock/unlock statements when using qt wait conditions?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm quite knew at doing multi threading, and despite the massive headache, I still find it incredibly fascinating. I'm using qt and have been examining tutorials and found one perfectly applicable to my situation which is streaming data into a circular buffer, one thread writing into it, one thread reading out of it. This is the tutorial [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-waitconditions.html). First let me ask you if i have chosen the right method in wait conditions.

I chose not to use semaphores because the size of the buffer may change at anytime from the main thread causing a reallocation and a readjustment of the read/write indices, and resizing the semaphores doesn't appear that easy. I didn't want to place an if comparison in the loop for whether to execute the body of the loop because it would have to do that over and over again until it could fit more data in the buffer, so wait conditions were my natural solution.

Secondly, i'm a bit confused by what the wait conditions are doing in their examples. It appears that they lock the mutex, check for the wait condition and block, continue when the condition is met, and then unlock the mutex right there. Doesn't that mean that accesses to the buffer for writing are entirely unprotected at that point?

Thirdly, I'm at a bit of a loss on how to end these threads when my main thread wants to stop. I cannot use a wait condition because i want them to run for as long as the main thread wishes, and i don't think i can signal across threads to tell it to quit. Is the only way to inform a thread to cease execution, to place an if somewhere constantly checking a bool located in the main thread every loop, and then wait for the threads to exit in the destructor? The issue with that is that with the wait conditions, i would have to first set the bool to exit, and then wake both the threads. I'm really confused on what to do here and any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the buffer accesses are protected by virtue of how the index of the data is selected:

1. the consumer sees no data in the buffer so blocks
2. the producer sees the buffer is not full so writes some data in the buffer at index `0`
   and wakes up the consumer and increments the index t write at index `1`
3. the consumer sees data and reads at index `0`

in particular the only way `i % buffersize` from the consumer would be the same as `i % buffersize` from the producer between the critical sections is if `numUsedBytes == 0` and you are the producer or `numUsedBytes == buffersize` and you are the consumer

seeing this you should be able to reason that neither producer nor consumer will be able to read or write to the same index simultaneously: ergo access is protected

this [solution is well researched](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer#Use_a_Fill_Count)

there are several issues with this implementation though: the if check is not enough should the condition get woken up for any reason. they should use a [QMutexLocker](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmutexlocker.html) so exceptions or early returns won't screw everything up:

```
{
    QMutexLocker lock(mutex.lock());
    while (numUsedBytes == BufferSize)
    {
         bufferNotFull.wait(&mutex);
         if(shouldStop)return;
    }
}
```

Comment: question about the QMutexLocker, the documentation tells me all it does is lock the mutex given in it's constructor and then unlocks when it's destroyed. The mutex is never destroyed here during the loop, so when is the mutex locked and unlocked for access to shouldStop, numUsedBytes, bufferSize, and buffer? Basically why did they have to wrap the wait statement in lock/unlock blocks as well?

Comment: the locker gets destroyed when it goes out of scope, so in my code after the while exits and goes outside the curly braces, then the locker gets destroyed and the mutex unlocks

Comment: well yes, i understood that, i meant about what happens in the while loop. In their example they wrap the if and wait condition in a mutex.lock() and mutex.unlock(), but in yours, all you did was do the wait. What was the purpose of them doing that?

Answer (score 1):

First, yes, wait conditions are the right tool for this job.

Their use of wait conditions is not the best, because sometimes a thread gets woken up prematurely. Their if statement should be a while loop, e.g.

```
while (numUsedBytes == 0)
    bufferNotEmpty.wait(&mutex);
```

Second, the producer and consumer are carefully written so that the producer owns some of the bytes in the buffer, and the consumer owns the others. That is, the consumer owns the part with unexamined data in it and the produce own the unused part. This is why they can safely read or write a byte in buffer, because they are guaranteed that the other thread isn't using that byte.

Third, ending threads like this is difficult, but your idea is mostly correct. If the main program knows when it is time to end, then change the wait loops to something like :

```
while (numUsedBytes == 0)
    bufferNotEmpty.wait(&mutex);
    if (TimeToEnd) {unlock(); return;}
```

and in main, when it's time to end you say

```
lock();
TimeToEnd = true;
wakeAll();
unlock();
joinAllThreads();
```

If the producer knows when it is time to end, then something very similar happens, and the main program just joins all the threads immediately after creating all the threads.

Comment: shouldn't there also be braces around the while body when testing `TimeToEnd`.